# How can I add bundled jars to my classpath in an Ant build task?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I have a plugin-project in Eclipse. I want to compile my code with ant. Now I need to add a jar to my classpath, which has also a couple of jars in its classpath. There are several packages exported, which are required to compile the code. When I add this jar to my dependencies and run the code with Eclipse, everything works fine. But ant somehow can't find the required imports. The Manifest of the bundle testfxplugin.jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Automatic-Module-Name: dummyjar
Bundle-SymbolicName: dummyjar
Export-Package: com.sun.glass.ui.monocle,org.hamcrest,org.hamcrest.cor
 e,org.hamcrest.internal,org.testfx.api,org.testfx.assertions.api,org.
 testfx.assertions.impl,org.testfx.framework.junit,org.testfx.internal
 ,org.testfx.matcher.base,org.testfx.matcher.control,org.testfx.osgi,o
 rg.testfx.osgi.service,org.testfx.robot,org.testfx.robot.impl,org.tes
 tfx.service.adapter,org.testfx.service.adapter.impl,org.testfx.servic
 e.finder,org.testfx.service.finder.impl,org.testfx.service.locator,or
 g.testfx.service.locator.impl,org.testfx.service.query,org.testfx.ser
 vice.query.impl,org.testfx.service.support,org.testfx.service.support
 .impl,org.testfx.toolkit,org.testfx.toolkit.impl,org.testfx.util
Bundle-Name: Dummyjar
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: libs/openjfx-monocle-8u76-b04.jar,libs/testfx-core-4
 .0.15-alpha.jar,libs/testfx-junit-4.0.15-alpha.jar,.,libs/org.hamcres
 t.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
Class-Path: libs/openjfx-monocle-8u76-b04.jar,libs/testfx-core-4
 .0.15-alpha.jar,libs/testfx-junit-4.0.15-alpha.jar,.,libs/org.hamcres
 t.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

Here is the ant-Target:

```
<path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="${test.lib}/testfxplugin.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${test.lib}/junit-4.9.jar" />
</path>

<target name="test-compile">
    <mkdir dir="${test.build}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${test.src}" destdir="${test.build}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: You would have to manually add all the entries from the Bundle-Class path in your Ant classpath. Note that builds like this are usually done using Maven with  Eclipse Tycho which understands how to build plug-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @greg-449, you will have to add all the required jars as part of classpath.
Something like this :

```
<classpath>
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</classpath>
```

This is just an example to include multiple (wildcard entries) jars. You can read more about it at [Path-like Structures](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)

This is basically a transitive dependency, ie your dependencies have their own dependencies. That is where Maven can be used, which automatically takes care of such dependencies. More on it here : [Maven Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)